# Eclipse is not adding any files to new gradle projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm currently trying to set up a Gradle project in the Eclipse IDE, with JDK 19, Gradle 7.6, and Buildship, on a fresh install of the Eclipse IDE. When I try and create a new gradle project from the "new -> project..." dialog, the gradle build wizard pops up, but after creating the project it only creates a folder with no files in it -- no build.gradle, no Java library, nothing. I've tried making a regular Java project, and that works, so it seems to be something specifically wrong with either my Gradle or Buildship installation, but I have no idea what it could be. I've tried doing a fresh install of both Buildship and Gradle 7.6, and it doesn't seem to help.

The only thing I have to go on is that there seems to be issues connecting to the Gradle build. One of the errors from the error log is shown below:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.initProjectIfNotExists(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.runInToolingApi(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectImportWizardController$5.run(ProjectImportWizardController.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.jvm.JavaHomeException: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.findExecutable(Jvm.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.getJavaExecutable(Jvm.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.forHome(Jvm.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.javaHomeMatches(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.whyUnsatisfied(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.isSatisfiedBy(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.isSatisfiedBy(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.getCompatibleDaemons(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:192)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connectToIdleDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:157)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:222)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:148)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:202)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.produceModel(PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:89)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
```

So my best guess is that my Java Home is wrong, but all the documentation I can find online says it's set right. So I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: What is the value of JAVA_HOME that it's complaining about that you think is correct? Why does the message mention Gradle 7.4.2?

Comment: So it's looking for the java.exe file in my C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\, which is definitely there -- I can go look at it right now, and it's what my Java_Home is pointing at. As for the gradle bit, that's honestly a really good catch, it must be getting my gradle files externally, which means it's probably not an issue with my gradle installation., and my gradle installation is probably also not doing anything useful.